# Dreamweaver + localhost WAMP PHP

Tags: php, wamp, dreamweaver

I have WAMP installed (and working) on my PC - localhost.
I have a site with PHP, and it works when I open it in Firefox localhost/path.
I use Adobe DreamWeaver CS6 to develop my site, but I can't use the design / live, because I must configure my localhost to work like a server for Dreamweaver - and I don't know how.
If someone could make a nice step by step guide which shows how to configure it I'll be glad. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A nice guide from Adobe themselves](http://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/set-testing-server.html)

Comment: I tried this, dosen't help.
Screenshot of the server dialog: http://i.imgur.com/Gyfme7H.png

Comment: add c:/wamp/www for server folder

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I found another answer - which is working
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/setup_testing_server.html

Answer (score 0):

this is for all kind of connectivity. You must try it.best of luck
http://www.extendstudio.com/blog/2010/03/how-to-make-a-testing-server-work/